# What is the working mechanism of SENSOR_TYPE_GRAVITY to get its data? - Android

Tags: android, android-sensors, gravity

I have a 3-D acceleration vector (a, b, c) obtained from an Android phone accelerometer.

I wish to calculate the angle between this vector (a, b, c) and the gravity vector, which points exactly downwards.

I notice that in Android, there is a way of getting gravity vector under the context of the phone coordinate system instead of the world coordinate system. By simply use sensor type `SENSOR_TYPE_GRAVITY`, I can get the 3-D gravity vector (d, e, f). Since both vectors are under the same coordinate system, the phone coordinate system. By simple vector inner product, their angle can be easily found.

After finding this angle, even if we move from the phone coordinate system to the real world coordinate system, the angle remains unchanged.

**My question:**

What is the working mechanism behind the `SENSOR_TYPE_GRAVITY`?

I don't think there is another hardware that measures the gravity. Thus, it is just the acclerometer who measures the gravity. How is the gravity extracted our of the resultant accleration?

I am asking because I am concerned with the accuracy of this way of getting the gravity.

If it is inaccurate, I can implement a LPF to filter the DC component, the gravity, out by myself. I am not sure whether getting it from `SENSOR_TYPE_GRAVITY` is more accurate than I do it myself.

================================== UPDATES =======================================

Just to clarify, can I get the BOTH acceleration and gravity data correctly with the following codes?

By correctly, I mean do the acceleration and the gravity belong to one same particular time instant? I need to use the values at ONE time instant. So the situation where the acceleration is for time=13:12:00 and the gravity is for a later time, say time=13:12:01 is NOT desired.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) { 

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) { 
        acceleration[0] = event.values[0];
        acceleration[1] = event.values[1];
        acceleration[2] = event.values[2];
    }

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY) {
        gravity[0] = event.values[0];
        gravity[1] = event.values[1];
        gravity[2] = event.values[2];
    }

}
```

Comment: LPF is not as accurate as using SENSOR_TYPE_GRAVITY. I think SENSOR_TYPE_GRAVITY is obtained by using Kalman filter on the accelerometer values.

Comment: @HoanNguyen Thanks for the comment. But why Kalman Filter can be used here?

Comment: It is fused using gyro. You can read the source code at https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/ics-mr1/services/sensorservice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three sensors Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY and Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION are related by the equation

```
"Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER" =  "Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY" + "Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION"
```

If you register for updates for all three, what you find is that Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER always arrives first, followed by Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY and Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION, and that the values always satisfy that equation.  Internally, Android is using filtering, and in particular a Kalman filter, to separate the two.

A low pass filter is a simple way of doing something similar.  However, a lot of thought will have gone into the Android mechanism, so I'm sure that if a low pass filter was better, then Android would have implemented that.

Comment: awesome! Thanks! Then may I ask you another thing? If it is as what you have said, then may I say that once the data from Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER vary, the data from Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY must also vary? i.e. I only need one condition: if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) to check whether the data from ALL 3 sensors have varied or not.

Comment: Unless the device is lying on a table (or similar), in which case the values are zero, the values will be changing all the time.  Acceleration is the change in speed, and any movement (however small) will be picked up.  So don't expect any of these values to be stable.  However, the simple answer to your question is "YES", if you get an `onSensorChanged` event for Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, then Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY and Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION have also changed, and almost immediately there will then be two further calls to `onSensorChanged`, one for each sensor.

Comment: could you please refer to my updated question post to help clarify this? Does the code above work as desired?

Comment: You will see two calls to `onSensorChanged`, but they will both relate to the same underlying reading from the accelerometer, so YES, I think the code will work.  Also, if you add code to monitor `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION`, then you can check what I say for yourself.  Remember that the `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` is seen first.

Comment: This answer doesn't fully answer the question.  The working mechanism

Comment: @Stochastically Shouldn't your equation be: "Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION" =  "Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY" + "Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER"? I thought linear acceleration is processed data from accelerometer without gravity.

Comment: @Bresiu I *think* my equation was correct, although it's ages since I looked at this stuff! The basic input is "Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER" because an accelerometer is a bit of hardware inside these devices that actually measures something. Clever code then tries to decompose that basic input into "Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY" (i.e. acceleration due to gravity which is roughly 9.8 metures/sec/sec) and "Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION" (i.e. acceleration due to the actual motion of the device). So the decomposition is all about explaining "Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER", hence my equation. But please test!

Comment: @Stochastically Ok, you are right, I thought a different way... I read this as: "To calculate TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION we need Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY AND Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER":)

Comment: Thanks for all this info. Could anyone provide a link to the source code where the Kalman filter for TYPE_GRAVITY is implemented? I'm having a really hard time finding it.

Comment: @SharkAlley a lot of android source code is open source so presumably it's there somewhere on https://source.android.com/ .  But if you really need an answer, I suggest you post a new question about this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!