# Source code for Kalman filter for Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY

Tags: android, android-sensors

I read that the output for Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY is computed using data from the accelerometer, with a Kalman filter applied.

[What is the working mechanism of SENSOR_TYPE_GRAVITY to get its data? - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102831/what-is-the-working-mechanism-of-sensor-type-gravity-to-get-its-data-android/17103724#comment54121580_17103724)

I would really like to see the source code for this implementation. I've tried searching on:

http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/

But I can't find the implementation. Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but this is what I get when I type in "Kalman" into the search engine you provided http://goo.gl/QXxKgF

Comment: Thanks for the input, but those results do not relate to Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY. (They come from the OpenCV graphics library.)